# Can You Make A Small Adjustment To A Style Based On Another Style In XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Is it possible to make small adjustments to styles based on other styles in XAML, I want to do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:PseudoType MostControls}" x:Key="WhatMostControlsLookLike">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:PseudoType ThisControl}" 
    x:Key="WhatThisControlLooksLike"
    BasedOn={StaticResource WhatMostControlsLookLike}">
    <Setter Property="Margin">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!-- Top, Right, and Bottom are 10 as per WhatMostControlsLookLike-->
            <Thickness>
                <!-- But Left is 10 times as thick-->
                <Thickness.Left>100</Thickness.Left>
            </Thickness>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That way, you redefine the Margin Property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You have to completely replace the Margin when setting it again.